# DBMS_RLS.add_policy: object_name not working

Tags: oracle, vpd

- Hi guys, I'm learning the VPD feature of Oracle and I've got stuck at these below codes.

```html
BEGIN
    DBMS_RLS.add_policy(
    object_schema    => 'user_bacsi_01',
    object_name      => 'HOSOBENHNHAN',
    policy_name      => 'VPD_POLICY_DOCTOR_SEE_PATIENT_INFO',
    policy_function  => 'FUNC_VPD_POLICY_DOCTOR_SEE_PATIENT_INFO'
    );
END;
/
```

- Error

```html
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RLS_INT", line 23
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RLS", line 54
ORA-06512: at line 2
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

- I've already created the table name 'HOSOBENHNHAN'. I don't understand the problem. Please help me!
- Thank you!

Comment: under which user you're trying this? user_bacsi_01? if not, be sure you have the proper grants.

Comment: The current user is sys which its role is SYSDBA

Comment: Try making the object schema upper case: `USER_BACSI_01`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Why don't you verify object name and owner from dba_objects? `select owner,object_name from dba_objects where upper(object_name) like 'HOSO%'`

Comment: It works. Actually, I don't understand the object_schema, I got it, object_schema is the owner of the object_name, thank you @Suresh